# JS whole page rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying give users the option of selecting a different homepage by clicking left or right, and having an entirely new page appear. I'm aware of a few jQuery carousels that accomplish this in a purely x axis, or y axis manner, but not a rotation. Ideally the background images will sync up, and the overall effect would be like a globe spinning, with a different set of elements at a different portion of the globe. The elements at each section of the globe still need to be interactive and

Does anyone have any ideas on that?

Comment: Do you have an example of what are you looking for? Is it a kind of scroller? page scroll?

Comment: Are you trying to do diagonal scrolling in a straight line, or something circular, like turning a dial?

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery, you should be able to do this using the .slideDown and slideUp methods.

Essentially, when they perform the action that you want to trigger a switch, you add a slideUp() to the 'current' container and do a slideDown() on the next one. The animations will run concurrently.

http://jsfiddle.net/g19fanatic/stLvj/

Comment: you would have to add some logic to make this 'circular' but that isnt too difficult. And this will go up and down... not left and right...

Comment: I think making it circular would be the difficult part and would require more than just "some logic", you'll need trigonometry.  I doubt jQuery is well equipped to do that out of the box.  Interesting problem... I'd love to see it done!

Comment: you see, i take circular to mean something different... I mean the looping of the elements. Meaning after the last element, it will circle back to the first one (my example does something similar but with the incorrect animation).  Having an exact example of what he's trying to accomplish would help tho...

Comment: gilly3 is right, I'm more interested in rotating an entire container 90 or some arbitrary number of degrees, AND still have it loop around after 360 degrees. I have never seen an exact JS implementation of this or even really close, it's always done in flash.

Comment: I did something involving circle animation just for fun many years ago, before there was IE7.  Maybe even before IE6.  It barely works today, running in quirks mode.  The code is a little embarassing by today's standards, but it was pretty slick in it's day.  http://gilly3.com/coolblocks/.  At least it shows that it is possible to animate divs in a circle without flash (or jQuery!).

Comment: You should take a look at using a canvas then. Google has some slick demos of doing pretty much anything that flash can do but just using html

Comment: The compromise I ended up coming to was making a static image and rotating it with .animate and a little plugin [link](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not many people here will write you a full solution, but they'll be happy to work through specific issues.

- Are these homepages on different domains and/or are they under your control?
- How globe-like do you mean? A kind of sphere distortion, or just seamlessly connected at the edges?
- How important is the smoothness of the concept?

Off the top of my head, here's how I would (attempt to) do it:

- Load the homepages in separate `iframes`
- Stretch the `iframe` to the window's dimensions
- Adapt a carousel script to animate `iframes` instead of `images`
- Some sort of "prev/next" controls overlaying the `iframe`. Maybe with `z-index`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not after a fully done out solution, just a nod in the right direction. As for the pages, they are all under my control, so thats not a concern. I just want them seamless at the edges, no need for spherical distortions. Smoother is better, naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Check out landing.js file on http://thetruth.com/ (or just let the page timer run to see the carousel)
What you want is basically that but with animations instead of fading the page in/out.

Just add CSS3 transforms to scale and slide instead of the fadein/out when a new page loads.
A polyfill will add the transform capability in JS (see jquery.transform.js, jquery.transition.js by https://github.com/louisremi and Modernizr)